# Suggestions of scripting web front end for C++

Tags: c++, frontend

Im currently learning C++ and Im interested in a web front end that can be fast as its C++ back end part. Which front ends does make a good combination?

Not looking for the best just the ones that can join cpp without using cgi. So please dont vote down.

---Update------

I actually develope my web applications in Java and is nice. Im looking at the C++ side since I want to give it a try. I learn a little of C++ on a college class 3 years ago and now Im reading the Deitel 8th Edition book to cover what I miss and review what I previosly learned. I'll read all your suggestions and will select a balance between productivity and speed. I admit it I am a performace addict that's the reason of my interest on this. Before asking this I thought Python could be used as a web front end. But maybe its not near C++ performance and thats why you didnt mentioned it.

-----Update #2------

What behaivor could have using python web frameworks or java servlets for the web engine and then connect it to C++? Will tomcat or the python server be a bottleneck?

Comment: Have you looked into [openGL](http://www.opengl.org/)?

Comment: Given that the OP mentions a web front end, maybe [WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/) is an option?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly want. Do you want to use a browser to access your C++ application? In this case, integrating a web server (HTTP server) into your application would be an option, or to implement your whole application as an Apache module plugin. Both cases aren't trivial, however. If you're currently *learning* C++, start with writing console applications. If you feel comfortable with core stuff, start with desktop GUIs. Writing a web application in C++ is a bit uncommon, I think.

Comment: Have a look at [mongoose, an embeddable web server](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/). On web client side, you should/could use AJAX, which requires only one static HTML page and a JSON or XML API implemented on your server, the rest of the client side is written in JavaScript.

Comment: @component Read that fairly quickly, you're right.  openGL would be a nice place for a beginner to start adding graphics to a C++ app though, imo

Comment: AtComponent 10: I'll check it out.
Atleemes: Yes I want to access my C++ application via the browser. I'll check that Apache Module Plugin, sounds fine. I'm not actually starting in C++, I know a little since I learn it at college. Now I am reading the Deitel book to cover what I missed on college C++ class. I'll check about mongoose and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's hard to find a web front end in C++ (probably what you are looking for is a C++ equivalent of [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/)). Back ends are more common and there're some frameworks to create web apps in C++. Facebook has [Hiphop](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2010/02/02/hiphop-for-php--move-fast/) for converting PHP code to C++ to speed up. But everything mostly boils down to HTML(5)/JavaScript/CSS. However, Qt framework has integration with WebKit and you can build applications using this framework which leverages HTML5/JavaScript/CSS3 in a C++ app (I'm not too familiar with it, so may be wrong). Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336018/Building-C-Applications-with-HTML5) by the way.

EDIT: On further googling, found [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), this might look interesting. :)

Comment: I'm more a Java than a PHP developer. I'll read about that Wt thing and will be back.